# Conditional Formatting TODAY() with Date + Time in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I am trying to do is highlight cells that contain both a date and time together, I would like it to ignore the time and highlight the cell if the date is equal to TODAY.

For example:

`-|    A    |        B         | 
1 | Option1 | 06/17/2020  0800 | 
2 | Option2 | 06/17/2020  1500 | 
3 | Option1 | 06/18/2020  2300 | 
4 | Option1 | 06/20/2020  0800 |`

I would want B1 and B2 highlighted if today was 06/17/2020.

I tried a few different formulas in conditional formatting I found on Google, but with no luck.
Thank you!

Comment: Is that text or an actual date/time in column B? (Does the cell change to a numeric value if you change the format to "General"?)

Comment: It would be text, it does not change value when changed from Date to General

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a rule based on the following formula:

```
=--(LEFT($B1,10))=TODAY()
```

Apply to column B.

[image]

Note that this assumes that the date portion is always in the format mm/dd/yyyy, i.e. it takes up the *10 left* characters.

Comment: Just out of curiosity and to hopefully be an excel master someday, what do the -- after the first = do?

Comment: That's the "double unary" - it converts the result of the `LEFT`, which is text, into an actual date (number), so that you can convert it to `TODAY`. It can be used in other contexts - more reading [here](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary), and elsewhere. You could just as easily use `DATEVALUE` instead of the `--` here.